# How to Integrate Linkedin,Facebook and Google + in My Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails version is 2.3.2.

Can any one send me some useful links that can be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these gems:

https://github.com/envylabs/BlueLightSpecial (facebook),
https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin

Haven't found anything related to google+ though...

Please, let me know if links above helped.